# Is "Asset" a reserved word in Ruby on Rails' MVC structure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple web app using Rails 5.1.3 & was hoping to use "Asset" as a financial object model.

Building a controller and model from the command line doesn't reveal any problems, but minitest's default controller test suite fails the destroy, update and create actions. Here's the feedback from the 'update' action test:

```
Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <405: Method Not Allowed> 
Response body: Method Not Allowed
```

I'm guessing that this model name conflicts with Rails' asset pipeline operations. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Why not do a global search replace (Asset -> YourAsset) and find out? (If I had my laptop handy I would quickly find out for you, just by firing up the rails console and looking for an existing Asset constant.)

Comment: I did, and saw the error disappear. The console doesn't return anything matching an Asset constant. Thanks!

Comment: Could be a routing thing instead of an actual namespace/constant clash: /assets/ is a special route. You'll have an easier life if you just accept a different name. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#changing-the-assets-path if you really want to change the default assets path. I'd really advise that you don't, as asset handling is a rabbithole of fun

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I definitely don't want to do any default asset path stuff & will live with a different model/controller name. Thanks for the pointer.